how to execute a function only when i send an order to trash
I built my site with woocommerce and I have a custom plugin for user points this plugin gives user points when the order status changes to wc-complate, this plugin works fine but when I change the status of an order from wc-completed to trash, the user's points are not updated, I want the points received for these orders to be removed from the user's account when I change the status of the order from wc-completed to trash

Are you looking for the transition_post_status hook?

It depend if you're using HPOS or not:
If not:
function my_custom_function_on_order_trash( $post_id ) {
    // Get the post type of the trashed item
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    // Check if the trashed item is an order
    if ( 'shop_order' === $post_type ) {
        // Your custom code here
      
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'my_custom_function_on_order_trash' );

If you’re using HPOS (High-Performance Order Storage) in WooCommerce, orders are no longer treated as standard posts, so wp_trash_post might not be the best hook to use. Instead, you should use WooCommerce-specific hooks to detect when an order is being moved to the trash.
Here’s how you can achieve that with HPOS:
function my_custom_function_on_order_trash( $order ) {
    if ( $order instanceof \Automattic\WooCommerce\Orders\Order ) {
        // Your custom code here

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_trash_order', 'my_custom_function_on_order_trash' );


And HPOS doesn't simulate the hooks so that other plugins keep working? That feels like an oversight.

@Rup
The 'wp_trash_post' hook should work correctly with HPOS because WooCommerce takes care of simulating most of the old hooks. However, there might be some circumstances where it is not triggered. I checked the lastest version (9.3.2) of the plugin and the hook 'woocommerce_before_trash_order' was found on "woocommerce\src\Internal\DataStores\Orders\OrdersTableDataStore.php" and "woocommerce\includes\data-stores\abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php". So that hook should be the best for HPOS compatibility.
